# Parse timestamp to the format I want in scala

Tags: java, scala, timestamp

I have something like this below:

```
scala> val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
format: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960

scala> format.format(new java.util.Date())
res3: String = 20150807135758
```

I want to change take **yyMMddhhmmss** out of the **timestamp**, but when do `toString` to the **timestamp**, I get an error

```
scala> val newDate = format.subString(2, 11)
<console>:10: error: value subString is not a member of    java.text.SimpleDateForm
at
   val newDate = format.subString(2, 11)
                        ^
```

I can see that this can be changed to String:

```
scala> val newDate = format.toString()
newDate: String = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960

scala> newDate
res7: String = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960

scala> newDate.substring(2, 11)
res8: String = va.text.S
```

But it doesn't really print out the way I want. How do I fix this?

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking, what do you want to achieve? you are calling `toString()` on `format` which is of type `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, the the `toString()` will then return the full class name plus `@` plus some JVM generated number

Comment: From the timestamp, so 20150807135758, I want 1508071357 extracted. yyyyMMddhhssss to yyMMddhhss.

Comment: ok hope my answer helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `substring()` on the `String` returned by `format(Date)` not on `format` object which is an instance of `SimpleDateFormat`:

`format.format(new java.util.Date()).substring(2, 11)`

Even better you can simply change your pattern to:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmmss")
format.format(new java.util.Date())
```

Results in `150807143842`.

In your example `format` is an instance of type `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. When you call `toString()` on it, it will return the name of the class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` plus `@` plus a JVM generated number describing this instance. This is the default `toString()` behavior in Java (and Scala) unless a class overrides `toString()`.

Comment: this definitely helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
scala> val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
format: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@5069d960

scala> format.toPattern.substring(2, 11)
res5: String = yyMMddHHm
```